# grub-probe run as root regulary

Tags: grub2, hard-drive, grub-efi

I have a problem.
I see that this command is launch by the system regularly and my PC become very very slow (because of lot of disk access)
Why have I this command running? How to fix that?

```
grub-probe --device /dev/sda5 --target=fs_uuid
```

PS: sda5 is my linux / partition in a dual boot PC

This is what i get from ps auxf command:

```
root      1695  0.0  0.0   4508  1600 ?        Ss   02:49   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
root      2685  0.2  1.2 248000 72352 ?        S    02:49   1:44  \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
root      2838  0.0  1.1 248852 69728 ?        S    02:51   0:22      \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
root      2843  0.0  2.2 154948 133508 pts/6   Ss+  02:51   0:04          \_ /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 10 --force-depends --force-remove-essential --remove linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic:amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-21:all linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-22:all linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic:amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-24:all linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic:amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic:amd64 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-24-generic:amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic:amd64 linux-tools-4.4.0-34-generic:amd64 linux-tools-4.4.0-34:amd64
root     24834  0.0  0.0   4508   744 pts/6    S+   12:17   0:00              \_ /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic.postrm remove
root     24836  0.0  0.0   4368  1660 pts/6    S+   12:17   0:00                  \_ run-parts --verbose --exit-on-error --arg=4.4.0-22-generic --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic /etc/kernel/postinst.d
root     28647  0.0  0.0   4508  1660 pts/6    S+   12:17   0:00                      \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
root     32166  0.0  0.0   4508  1772 pts/6    S+   14:00   0:00                          \_ /bin/sh /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
root       826  0.0  0.0   4508   192 pts/6    S+   14:18   0:00                              \_ /bin/sh /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
root      1230  0.0  0.0  32444  4168 pts/6    D+   14:27   0:00                              |   \_ /usr/sbin/grub-probe --device /dev/sda2 --target=fs
root       827  0.0  0.0  23372  1164 pts/6    S+   14:18   0:00                              \_ sed -e s/^/\t/
f
```

Comment: Do you have a rough count on how often that runs? What happens here is that a system upgrade tries to remove old kernels on which the grub config will be rebuild - hence the probe. Check which kernel packages are still installed on your machine. If you still have 4.4.0-22 than this job fails and you should remove them on a terminal to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @FredFoo, I think this happen every time the system upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is that command that makes your machine slow - grub-probe just probes for simple information values of a disk or partition.

You can dig deeper into what is going on by knowing who called it when you see it in the process list. Do a

```
ps auxf
```

to get a tree'ish output and find the parent process to grub-probe.

You can also check your etc directory for any calls to that program

```
sudo find /etc -type f -exec grep grub-probe {} \;
```

This should give you a list of files that have the string grub-probe in it. Looking into the file and where it is used may give you the answer.